# Преобразование содержания файла при помощи Rust

Tags: регулярные-выражения, rust

У меня есть задача: преобразовать ссылки такого типа: `[[content]]`, в ссылки такого типа: `[content](content)`, или такие ссылки: `[[content|rename]]` в такие: `[rename](content)`.
Я могу использовать парсинг файла и заменение элементов, но мне будет более удобен вариант с regex. Какие есть способы такого преобразования?

Comment: (нет рабочих примеров кода т.к. я не понимаю, как реализовать такую задачу)

Comment: а где тогда примеры входных и выходных данных?

Comment: @Fat-Zer , посмотрите внимательней текст вопроса. На входе `[[content]]`, на выходе `[content](content)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не большой специалист по расту, но я чуточку знаю регулярки. Вооружившись [докой](https://docs.rs/regex/1.4.2/regex/) и чуточку поэкспериментировав, я набросал такое

```
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let text = "hello, [[http://stackoverflow.com]] and [[Google|https://google.com]]!";
    let re = Regex::new(r"\[\[(?P<t>[^|\[\]]*?)\|(?P<u>[^|\[\]]*?)\]\]").unwrap();
    let repl = re.replace_all(text, "[$t]($u)");
    println!("{}", repl);
    let re2 = Regex::new(r"\[\[(?P<t>[^|\[\]]*?)\]\]").unwrap();
    let repl2 = re2.replace_all(&repl, "[$t]($t)");
    println!("{}", repl2);
}
```

Comment: С недавнего времени я также пришел к использованию регулярок. Получились неплохие функции, но большинство того, что они делают оказалось бесполезно для этой задачи. Спасибо за простой вариант решения.